# Getting the value of a SELECT box in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a select box:

```
<select id="item1" name="Item 1">
  <option> </option>
  <option> Camera </option>
  <option> Microphone </option>
  <option> Tripod </option>
</select>
```

And I have this JavaScript:

```
var item1= document.getElementById("item1").value;
```

`item1` always shows empty, never the option selected. However, this works in [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using item.value works for all browsers except very very old ones (Netscape 4 anyone?). The reason it does not work in this case is because you have no value attribute in options. You should declare value for each attribute. What you currently have is only "text" property, which normally defaults to value whenever no value is declared. Alternately you can push some code in the window onload event to make "value" of each of these options same as "text".

A third way you can use the code below, which is the old-fashioned way:

```
var s = document.getElementById('item1');
var item1 = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: no error per se, i have a check that checks for a value, and the value is never there

Comment: Greg, @Marco Z's answer (using `.text` instead of `.value`) worked for me on IE7. Maybe update answer, or explain why not?

Comment: I usually just use jQuery for this. Add a class to the element, whether its a select, input, textarea or hidden field, and then use $('element').val() to retrieve its value. Easy peasy.

Answer (score 14):

Since your option tags don't have the attribute "value" IE6 and IE7'll return you an empty string.
You should read the value from the "text" field of the Option object like this:

```
var item1 = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
```

in item1 you'll have the value you need without breaking the compatibility with Firefox and IE 8.

Answer (score 3):

As an addendum to answer #1, be careful as <select>.selectedIndex can be -1 some times which will throw an exception when passed into <select>.options[n]. As such, you might want do do a quick test:

```
var s = document.getElementById('item1');
var item = (-1 != s.selectedIndex)? 
               s.options[s.selectedIndex] : null;
```

**EDIT**

Per Tim's comment, s.selectedIndex can be -1 if you set it via JavaScript or you create an empty <select> box.

Comment: Do you know when `selectedIndex` can be -1? I've never seen that.

Comment: The only way `selectedIndex` can be -1 is if you've explictly set it to be -1 via JavaScript.

Comment: However, I've downvoted too hastily and now I can't remove it unless you edit. Sorry.

Comment: The JSREF states: "If no option is selected, selectedIndex has a value of -1."

Answer (score 1):

Code to get a vaiable **columnName** from the SELECT box called **layerDetails.styleColumn** (SELECT tag has same name and Id), that works across ALL browsers  ...

```
var columnName = document.getElementsByName('layerDetails.styleColumn')[0].value;
if ( columnName == null || columnName == '' )
  {
  columnName = document.getElementById('layerDetails.styleColumn').value;
  }

if ( columnName == null || columnName == '' )
  {
  var select = document.getElementById('layerDetails.styleColumn');
  columnName= select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  if ( columnName == null || columnName == '' )
    {
    columnName= select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    }
  }
```