# jQuery - hide() is not working in Internet Explorer 9 compatibility mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I'm having an issue with hiding and showing li elements with [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). My code works in Chrome and Internet Explorer 9, but if Internet Explorer 9 enters compatibility mode, or is set to a lower browser, it silently fails.

The idea is to have a drop down that filters by class and have the results paged. For the sample below, I have removed most of the paging code.

As far as I can tell, the issue is with `selector.children().hide();`, though I'm not certain about this.

I ran the HTML through the [W3C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium) validator, and it seems fine, while I get no JavaScript errors in the Chrome tools, and no obvious errors in the Internet Explorer development tools (though I am less familiar with these and could be missing something).

If you save the below into an HTML file, you should get a drop down that when selected filters the `li` elements. in Chrome at least:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            //<![CDATA[
                function buildPaging(filterClass) {
                    var selector = $('.paging');
                    selector.wrap("<div class='simplePagerContainer'></div>");

                    var pageSize = 2;
                    var pageCounter = 1;
                    var currentPage = 1;
                    var step =0;

                    selector.children().each(function (i) {
                        var item = $(this);
                        var hasClass = false;
                        if (filterClass !== undefined &&
                            filterClass !== '' &&
                            filterClass !== 'Sites:' &&
                            item.hasClass(filterClass)) {

                            hasClass = true;
                        }
                        else
                            if (filterClass === undefined ||
                                filterClass === '' ||
                                filterClass === 'Sites:') {

                                hasClass = true;
                            }

                        if (step < pageCounter * pageSize && step >= (pageCounter - 1) * pageSize && hasClass) {
                            $(this).addClass("simplePagerPage" + pageCounter);
                            step++;
                        }
                        else
                            if (hasClass) {
                                $(this).addClass("simplePagerPage" + (pageCounter + 1));
                                pageCounter++;
                                step++;
                            }
                    });
                    selector.children().hide();
                    selector.children(".simplePagerPage" + currentPage).show();
                };

                function cleanPaging() {
                    $('li').removeClass('simplePagerPage1 simplePagerPage2 simplePagerPage3 simplePagerPage4 simplePagerPage5 simplePagerPage6 simplePagerPage7 simplePagerPage8')
                    $('.simplePagerNav').remove();
                }

                $(document).ready(function() {
                   buildPaging();
                });

                var selectedItem;

                function hideMessage(period) {
                    var classList = $('.EMI_Message_Option');
                    selectedItem = period;
                    var keep;
                    for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
                        if (classList[i].innerHTML !== period) {
                            $('.' + classList[i].innerHTML).hide();
                        }
                        else {
                            keep = classList[i].innerHTML;
                        }
                    }
                    $('.' + keep).show();
                    cleanPaging();
                    buildPaging(period);
                }
            //]]>
        </script>

        <div class="EMI_Messages">
            <div class="EMI_Messages">

            <div class="MessageDropdown">
                <select onchange="hideMessage(this.value)">
                    <option>Sites:</option>
                    <option>CSR</option>
                    <option>Sales</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <ul class="paging">
                <li class="CSR">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <a href="http://example.com/">CSR</a>
                        </div>
                        <div>byline</div>
                        <div>11/26/2012 12:00:00 AM</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="Sales">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <a href="http://example.com/">Sales</a>
                        </div>
                        <div>sample text</div>
                        <div>11/21/2012 12:00:00 AM</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="pager"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by this piece of HTML:

```
<select onchange="hideMessage(this.value)">
```

In some versions of IE, `this.value` is not being passed as desired to the `hideMessage()` function.  It is passed as an empty string so the code doesn't work.

It works for me if that is changed to this:

```
<select onchange="hideMessage(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
```

FYI, here is your code with the fix applied in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9hUK9/

Now that we see the problem, you can see a similar Q&A here: [Getting the value of a SELECT box in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539032/getting-the-value-of-a-select-box-in-internet-explorer)

---

Unrelated to the problem you asked about, did you realize that every time you call `buidPaging()`, it does an additional `.wrap("<div class='simplePagerContainer'></div>");` so your DOM structure gets deeper each time that is called?

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 that was exactly the issue. Sorry for taking so long, I asked the question at the end of work, and just got in (in the U.K).