# How to get the select box values in a variable

Tags: javascript

i have a selectbox  which have values from 1 to 4 and I need to put the value I select in a javascript variable and send it in a function.Here is the way I am trying to do that..

```
<form enctype="application/json" method="post">

 <select id="select" name="options">
    <option>Choose Your Option</option>
    <option value="1"> 1</option>
    <option value="2"> 2</option>
    <option value="3"> 3</option>
    <option value="4"> 4</option>
</select>



<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="aMethod()"/>
```

I need this values in a variable and want to put that  value in this method so that I can use that.can anybody help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539032/getting-the-value-of-a-select-box-in-internet-explorer possible duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var select = document.getElementById('select');
var value = select.value;
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shryme/7YYu6/)

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the selected value like this:

```
var val = document.getElementById("select").value;
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ah7TU/