# document.getElementById() returns blank value

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I use `IE11`.

I was trying to figure out why my `document.getElementById("Courier0")` returns blank value.

However when I debug page and open that object, 
I noticed `ie9_value` holds the correct string passed on from page.

[image]

Does anyone know how to get the value for this awkward case?

I tried:

```
if(document.forms[0].Courier0.value)

 if(document.getElementById("Courier0").value)

 var e = document.getElementById("Courier0");
 if(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value)
```

None of these seem to work.

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539032/getting-the-value-of-a-select-box-in-internet-explorer)

```
var e = document.getElementById("Courier0");
 if(e.options[e.selectedIndex].text)
```