# Are there any other opportunities than ".value" to get the content of your drop-down-menu in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xslt

I am creating a table with dynamically rows and fixed columns. I have a drop-down-menu which contents depends on a xml file. To use the actual content of my drop-down-menu I am using `.value`. This works great on Firefox but not on Internet Explorer. If I write the content of `filterDropDown` into the console with `console.log(filterDropDown);` I do get empty entries on IE and correct entries on Firefox.

Here some Javascript Code:

```
var dropdown;
dropdown = document.getElementById('modelRangeDropdown');
filterDropDown = dropdown.value;
```

Here some xslt Code:

```
<table id="myTable">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="150" style="background-color:e2e2e2"></col>         
        </colgroup>
        <tr  style ="background-color:a5a5a5">
            <th rowspan="2">model
                <select id="modelRangeDropdown" onclick="test_internet_explorer()">
                     <option selected="selected">All</option>
                     <xsl:for-each select="logstore/plane">
                        <option>
                         <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
                        </option>
                     </xsl:for-each>                    
                </select>                   
            </th>
```

Comment: `optionElement.text` will give you the text.

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539032/getting-the-value-of-a-select-box-in-internet-explorer. Sorry. As I only saw``var item1= document.getElementById("item1").value;`` what did not work I have written my question here. The working line is: ``var item1= document.getElementById("item1").text;``

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Getting the value of a SELECT box in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539032/getting-the-value-of-a-select-box-in-internet-explorer).

Problem solved with:
`filterDropDown = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].text;`